# How to route MIDI CC #7 to instrument instead of track

Tags: midi, logic-pro, volume

In Logic Pro 9, by default, the MIDI CC#7 is assigned to the volume of an instrument track.

I need to skip this assignment so the MIDI CC#7 goes directly to the virtual instrument.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Environment. Drop in a Fader that listens to incoming MIDI CCs and transforms them into Fader messages. Then figure out which settings will get you to your virtual instrument. You may also need a transformer to filter MIDI CC7 from hitting your sequencer input.